# Clustering items in a grid

Tags: typescript, algorithm, math, lodash

> Background: The puzzle grid size can be 16x16, 8x8 or 4x4, and the difficulty varies with the similarity of the number of colors. The quantities of the seven colors are different, and the objective of the game is to find the most/least amount of colors within the puzzle grid.

I want the colors to be as clustered together as possible rather than dispersed throughout the puzzle grid, and each coordinate can only be occupied by one color. The final result generated is expected to completely fill up and form seven pieces of puzzle with each color having its own side, like a Tangram.

How can I create an algorithm for clustering colors in a puzzle game?
Thank you for your help!

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clustering-3ptu3s

> Example: (4x4)

[image: game]

```
{ row: 0, column: 0, color: 0}
{ row: 0, column: 1, color: 1}
{ row: 0, column: 2, color: 2}
{ row: 0, column: 3, color: 3}

{ row: 1, column: 0, color: 3}
{ row: 1, column: 1, color: 4}
{ row: 1, column: 2, color: 0}
{ row: 1, column: 3, color: 1}

{ row: 2, column: 0, color: 2}
{ row: 2, column: 1, color: 3}
{ row: 2, column: 2, color: 2}
{ row: 2, column: 3, color: 1}

{ row: 3, column: 0, color: 1}
{ row: 3, column: 1, color: 1}
{ row: 3, column: 2, color: 1}
{ row: 3, column: 3, color: 3}
```

desired output:

```
{ row: 0, column: 0, color: 0}
{ row: 0, column: 1, color: 0}
{ row: 0, column: 2, color: 2}
{ row: 0, column: 3, color: 2}

{ row: 1, column: 0, color: 3}
{ row: 1, column: 1, color: 4}
{ row: 1, column: 2, color: 2}
{ row: 1, column: 3, color: 1}

{ row: 2, column: 0, color: 3}
{ row: 2, column: 1, color: 3}
{ row: 2, column: 2, color: 3}
{ row: 2, column: 3, color: 1}

{ row: 3, column: 0, color: 1}
{ row: 3, column: 1, color: 1}
{ row: 3, column: 2, color: 1}
{ row: 3, column: 3, color: 1}
```

Comment: This is underspecified and allows an uncountable number of solutions, that's not really suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @cafce25 I have added codesandbox, do I need to specify the required algorithm?

Comment: Unless you do I fear this question is not "a practical, answerable problem" from [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You could go like this:

Think of your colored boxes as a single (sorted by color) line. and than put this line in the box (odd row from left to right, even row from right to left)

Example

```
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4

becomes:

0 0 1 1   ->
1 1 1 1   <-
2 2 2 3   ->
4 3 3 3   <-
```

Maybe not the nicest way of 'clustered' but a least all boxes of same color are connected.

---

Also a spiral patter would work

```
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4

becomes:

0 0 1 1  
3 3 3 1  
2 4 3 1  
2 2 1 1
```

or any other space filling continuous pattern ;-)

A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve might give the nicest results of this approach. (I used a **Hilbert curve** here)

```
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4

becomes:

1 1 2 2 
1 1 2 3 
1 1 3 3 
0 0 3 4
```

Comment: @Thomas I think you missed the fact that every other row traveres in reverse so for your input the algo provided would give `1,1,2,2 4,3,3,2` i.e. it **does** zig-zag, maybe you need to re-read the answer?